# Drop Mime data (csv file) into QTableView with custom QSqlTableModel is not working

Tags: mime, pyside6, drop, qsqltablemodel

I'm using a `QTableView` along with a superclassed `QSqlTableModel` to display a `sqlite` table into Qt and inserting new records dropping a csv file.

I have followed the [doc](https://%60https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views%60) and came up with the example reported below. I have recreated a very light reproducible example to show what is happening to my code, no sanity check or quality code has been intentionally used. It's tested against `PySide6`

```
import sys

from qtpy.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView, QWidget
from qtpy.QtCore import QModelIndex, QMimeData, Qt
from qtpy.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQuery
from pandas import read_csv

def create_table():
    # Dummy very simple table
    _query_str = """CREATE TABLE MyTable ( 
    ID     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Field1 INTEGER,
    Field2 TEXT);"""

    query = QSqlQuery(db=db, query=_query_str)
    query.exec_()

class MyTableModel(QSqlTableModel):

    def __init__(self, table_name, db):
        QSqlTableModel.__init__(self, db=db)
        self.setTable(table_name)

    def canDropMimeData(self, data: QMimeData, action: Qt.DropAction, row: int, column: int, parent: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        return True # <-- Just for the example

    def supportedDropActions(self) -> Qt.DropAction:
        return Qt.DropAction.CopyAction | Qt.DropAction.MoveAction | Qt.DropAction.LinkAction

    def dropMimeData(self, data: QMimeData, action: Qt.DropAction, row: int, column: int, parent: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        csv_filename = data.urls()[0].toLocalFile()
        df = read_csv(csv_filename, delimiter=',', header=0)

        for _, row in df.iterrows():
            record = self.record()
            record.remove(0) # <-- Remove the ID field
            record.setValue('Field1', row['Field1'].values[0])
            record.setValue('Field2', row['Field2'].values[0])
            self.insertRecord(-1, record)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # In memory database just for the purpose of the example
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE", ":memory:")
    db.open()
    if not db.open():
        raise "Database not opened"
    create_table()
    app = QApplication([])
    table = QTableView()
    model = MyTableModel('MyTable', db)
    table.setModel(model)
    table.setAcceptDrops(True)
    table.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I get is that `canDropMimeData` and `supportedDropActions` are correctly called, but (using debug) **`dropMimeData` is never called**

And the below image shows that, even if `canDropMimeData` returns `True`, the file seems not to be accepted.

[image]

## Edit 1 - QSqlTableModel issue

I found out that the problem is with `QSqlTableModel`. If I use a bare `QStandardItemModel`, everything works fine. Any work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, item models don't provide drag and drop support.

In order to properly allow that, many aspects have to be checked, including that the [`flags()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) returned by any index that would accept drop *must* also have the `Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled`.

If you want to allow that only for the model (drop on an empty area, not on items), that index would be the *root* index, aka, an invalid index:

```py
    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super().flags(index)
        if not index.isValid():
            flags |= Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
        return flags
```

Comment: I was missing that piece of information. Thank you. I should infer that QStandardItemModel implement that flag, am I wrong?

Comment: Anyway, I was not able to find this info inside the Model/View Framework documentation. Before I submit an issue with the doc, have you got any ref?

Comment: It's explained in the model view programming guide related to [subclassing and drag&drop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html#enabling-drag-and-drop-for-items). I strongly suggest you to take your time to read that (don't make the same mistake I did years ago, when I saw the length of that document and decided it was too much...)

Comment: Great, I missed that paragraph while reading the rest! Thank you again